# What is the advantages in using rmi without connecting to the database directly

Tags: java, database, rmi

We have asked to design an application for a company which has 10 branches.

they need a distributed database app, using that they can store and retrieve data of other branches. In order to achieve that i'm planning access the database through a network using the ip address for the connection string.

But i found some articles which say that using RMI
technology is the best way to achieve this. But i can't find any detailed advantages using rmi over directly connecting the apps to the database. Is it necessary to use RMI technology?
I don't know about rmi. Please give me a detailed answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: RMI requires a lot understand of how interfaces work and a solid understanding of serialization.  If you've never done it then you really should do a proof of concept, I'm sure it will work for you and is a better alternative then a fat client that is directly accessing the DB.

Comment: It makes sense not to expose the databases directly over the network. RMI is just one of many ways of accomplishing that.

Comment: Can you please mention some other ways to do that?

Comment: A web service. CORBA. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is RMI the best technology for doing this?  We'd have to agree on "best".  But my first reaction is "no".

The answer depends on whether those branches access the data over a secure network, internal to the company, or if they do it via browser and the public Internet.

RMI might be acceptable if all the branches are inside the firewalls on the same secure network.  If all of them can deal with Java clients you'll be able to make it work.

But if they're going over the public Internet the only solution that makes sense is HTTPS through port 443.  Clients will be written in HTML5 and CSS3 to run in browsers.

Regardless of the answer to that question, I think you want to put an intermediary between clients and the database in every case.  You don't want clients accessing data directly, because it's insecure.  The intermediary will be responsible for:

1. Authentication and authorization of users.
2. Validating request data.
3. Binding requests to queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.
4. Logging and monitoring.
5. Transaction maintenance.

RMI makes sense only if all the servers and clients are Java-based.

A more modern approach would use HTTP web services, either SOAP or REST, instead of RMI.  This has the advantage of working with non-Java clients.  You'll be in a better position for mobile clients that way, too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer, can you please give me some references to learn more about intermediary? As i am new to java i'm don't have much experience in network related programming, appreciate your help

Comment: Like I said, Google for REST services.  Spring 4 makes REST services pretty easy.  HTTP takes care of all the networking - you just need URLs.  http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/